# Fade animation when scrolling horizontal table view

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uitableview, uiviewanimation

I have a horizontal table view and want to change images each 5 secs. I want to change images with fade animation so the old image fades out and the new one fades in. So i call this method:

```
self.slideTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:5
                                                   target:self
                                                 selector:@selector(slideToNextImage)
                                                 userInfo:nil
                                                  repeats:YES];
```

And here is my `slideToNextImage:`

```
 self.lastIndexPath = indexPath;
 [UIView beginAnimations:@"FadeAnimations" context:nil];
 [UIView setAnimationDuration:2];
 self.horizontalView.alpha = 0.1f;
 [self.horizontalView.tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:self.lastIndexPath
         atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionMiddle
              animated:NO];
 [UIView commitAnimations];
 [UIView beginAnimations:@"FadeAnimations" context:nil];    
 [UIView setAnimationDuration:2];
 self.horizontalView.alpha = 1.0f;
 [UIView commitAnimations];
```

With my realisation the image fades too fast and i see the second image scrolling with no fade animation

Comment: can you give some more information about what you want to do and what the problem is?!

Comment: please, make some screenshot to specify your asking.

Comment: sorry, edited my post, hope this will help

Comment: I can not see any screenshot. :(

Answer (score 3):

the second animation starts without waiting for the first to end.

Try something like this instead:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:2.0 animations:^{
    self.horizontalView.alpha = 0.1f;
    [self.horizontalView.tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:self.lastIndexPath
                                         atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionMiddle
                                                 animated:NO];

} completion:^(BOOL finished) {
    [UIView animateWithDuration:2 animations:^{
        self.horizontalView.alpha = 1.0f;
    }];
}];
```

Comment: thanks, this worked, but animation isn't smooth I see some lag when scrollToRowAtIndexPath: is performed. Is it possible to make it smooth ?

Comment: This code likely isn't the problem that's causing the animation to be choppy.  What else are you doing simultaneously to eat up processing power/use up a ton of memory?

Comment: so the scrolling should not be animated? You could move the scrollToRow method call inside the completion block right before your second animation!

Comment: Yes, I did so and it worked, but the animation is not smooth. I see some blinking when scrollToRowAtIndexPath: is performed. I saw same functionality in the other apps that works really very smooth. Maybe I'm using wrong approach ? And scrolling the table view is not the solution ?